# CSS drop down menu is working in Mozilla, Chrome but not in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I implemented a drop down navigation menus in my blog, but it's not working properly in IE (any version). It's working in Chrome and Mozilla fine.

What should be done to make it compatible to IE?

The CSS I added is below:

```
#mbtnavbar {
/*        background: #B0E2FF;*/
    width: 780 px; 
    color: #FFF; 
        margin: 0 px;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        border-top:5 px solid #960100;
        height:30 px;

}

#mbtnav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mbtnav ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mbtnav li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
        border-left:0 px solid #333;
        border-right:0 px solid #333;
        height:35px;
}
#mbtnav li a, #mbtnav li a:link, #mbtnav li a:visited {
    color: ;
    display: block;
   font:normal 13px Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
   margin: 5; 
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px; 
        text-decoration: none;


}
#mbtnav li a:hover, #mbtnav li a:active {
    background: #0066FF;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;



}

#mbtnav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}
#mbtnav li ul {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height: auto;
    /*Width of drop down menu*/
    width: 180px;
    margin: -2px;
    padding: 0;
}
#mbtnav li ul a {
    width: 140px;
}
#mbtnav li ul ul {
    margin: -25px 0 0 161px;
}
#mbtnav li:hover ul ul, #mbtnav li:hover ul ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}
#mbtnav li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}
#mbtnav li:hover, #mbtnav li.sfhover {
    position: static;
}

#mbtnav li li a, #mbtnav li li a:link, #mbtnav li li a:visited {
    background: #B0E2FF;
    width: 360px;
    color: ;
    display: block;
    font:normal 13px Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
z-index:9999;
border-bottom:1px dotted #333;


}
#mbtnav li li a:hover, #mbtnavli li a:active {
    background: #0066FF;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Anand

Comment: Please add some relevant code (and maybe a JSFiddle example) here. With only an external link, the question will have no value to future readers once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: It means you're not doing it right. I've done this effect at least five different ways and they all work in all browsers first time. None of them rely on such loopy practices as `left: -999em;`.

Comment: @Kolink : Please let me know how to correct this.

Comment: @Kolink - It's working in all the modern browsers so he's doing everything right. Fixing IE is a given in almost everything.

Comment: Not if you work in IE in the first place. If only all developers could get that through their heads. Use "superior" browers for your day-to-day browsing if you will, but always use IE for developing. As for fixing this, I don't know (which is why I didn't post an answer). Try starting over and thinking about what you're doing. Imagine, for a moment, if the standards decided that it's valid to have elements in negative coordinates and scrollbars should be added to accomodate them. Your current method would give unwieldly scrollbars to the left.

Comment: @Kolink - Using IE as your test browser is coding to a bug. You MUST use the most standards compliant browser to test compliant markup. You don't use a broken calculator to test your math so you don't use a broken browser to test your code.

Comment: Well, in my large amount of experience, I have learned this: "If it works in IE and avoids IE-hacks or extensions, it works in all browsers." I've never been wrong about that, which is why I cringe whenever I see any form of "hack to make it work in IE".

Comment: @Kolink - If you code in IE, then you have to adjust to the other far more modern browsers. If you use a modern browser, you only have to adjust for IE. I'd rather write proper, working code the first time. I don't know anyone who does it any other way.

Comment: I do write proper, working code. And it ALWAYS works in ALL browsers, with no fiddling around making it work. Sadly, once you kick IE away as useless, you can never come back. IE is bad, but it's still a reasonable browser.

Comment: @Rob - don't be ridiculous.  Just because something works in anything, doesn't mean its "right". For example, the site referenced has 307 errors when you validate it.  How exactly is that "doing it right"?

Comment: @MystereMan - As I already said, it works in the modern browsers. It doesn't work in IE. He's at least doing a lot of things right and only IE fails  as it always does. I agree 307 errors is ridiculous, though.

Comment: @Rob - No, it doesn't.  Just because it works doesn't mean its right, or correct, or even standards compliant.  All browsers render invalid code differently, just because chrome and ff render his invalid code the way he wan'ts doesn't mean it's correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fix your errors.  The site has 307 validation errors.  invalid markup is the #1 reason why pages don't render properly from one browser to another.  Many people (myself included) won't even look at your CSS until you have valid markup.